# How to get security profile of AWS Connect user outside of the application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am working on building a call center application using the AWS Connect Streams API and AWS-SDK. I want to add a feature that is only accessible to User/Agent who are of "Admin" Security Profile. The feature is going to create a table in DynamoDB.
I know I can control the access to the DynamoDB but if there is a way to know or get the security profile of the user, I can use it for many other authentications.

Streams API I am talking about- https://github.com/aws/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Connect API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_ListSecurityProfiles.html) just released allows you to do this now.